# London equations - what is the mass is present?

Tags: condensed-matter, mass, superconductivity

The London equations are given by:
\[
 \newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>} \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|} \newcommand{\braoket}[3]{\left<#1\right|#2\left|#3\right>}
 \vec E=\f{m}{n_s e^2} \p{\vec j_s}{t}=\p{}{t} \l \Lambda \vec j_s\r\]
\[ \vec B=-\nabla \times \l\f{m}{n_se^2}\vec j_s\r\]
The book (Annett, 2004; pg60) states that (by definition of $n_s$) the mass $m$ is the "bare electron mass in vacuum" whilst (Blatt, 1964; pg22) explicitly uses the effective mass and charge. Which of these is correct? Should I be using the effective/band mass or the bare vacuum mass?

Comment: What does it change for you to use one or the other ? If you're trying to fit some data, try both ... In London's theory of first generation superconductors, it's the bare electron mass which appears, but in complex systems (especially heavy fermions with anisotropic effective mass tensor), why not using this as a fitting parameter ?